# HttpClient async - Too fast skipping webservice requests

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I have an issue where i loop over about 31 web service URLs.
If I put a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in the top code, it will work perfectly, but if I remove this, I only get success on 10 (sometimes less and sometimes more) request out of 31. How do I make it wait?

**Code**

```
foreach(var item in ss)
{ 
   //Call metaDataApi(url,conn,name,alias)
}

 public static void metadataApi(string _url, string _connstring, string _spname, string _alias)
        {
           // Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Metadata creation - Table Creation
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = _url;

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CHECKING");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("IS OK");
                        string json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                       //Doing some stuff not relevant

                     }
                }
            }
         }
```

**How it can look**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look to use `async/await` where you can, but you could try something like this:

```
// you should share this for connection pooling  
public static HttpClient = new HttpClient();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // build a list of tasks to wait on, then wait
    var tasks = ss.Select(x => metadataApi(url, conn, name, alias)).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}

public static async Task metadataApi(string _url, string _connstring, string _spname, string _alias)
{
    string url = _url;
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    Console.WriteLine("CHECKING");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IS OK");
        string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //Doing some stuff not relevant

    }
}
```

One thing to note, this will try to run many in parallel. If you need to run them all one after the other, may want to make another `async` function that waits on each result individually and call that from the `Main`. `.Result` is a bit of an antipattern (with modern c# syntax, you can use `async` on the main function) but for your script it should be "ok", but I'd minimize usage of it (hence why I wouldn't use `.Result` inside of a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try too look into this and return back when I have looked into it.